# NSubstitute if-else condition

Tags: methods, call, nsubstitute

Good day! I need your help, I have next tests:

```
    [SetUp]
    public void SetUp()
    {
        controller = Substitute.For<IApplicationController>();
        view = Substitute.For<ICamerasView>();
        presenter = new CamerasPresenter(controller, view);
        argument = InitializeDevicesList();
        presenter.Run(argument);
    }

    private List<string> InitializeDevicesList()
    {
        List<string> devicesList = new List<string>();
        Device device = new Device();

        devicesList.Add(device.Name);

        return devicesList;
    }

    [Test]
    public void RunIfDeviceListIsNotEmpty()
    {
        view.DidNotReceive().SetUIOnNoConnectedDevices();
        view.Received().FillCamerasListView(argument);
        view.Received().Show();

    }
```

which actually tests next code

```
    public override void Run(List<string> argument)
    {
        connectedCameras = argument;
        if(connectedCameras.Count == 0)
        {
            SetUIOnNoConnectedDevices();
        }
        else
        {
            FillCamerasListView();
        }
        View.Show();
    }
```

And my issue is that FillCamerasListView method isn't calling in test. But as it expected it called in Run method in this case. So, I can't imagine what is the problem, so I will be very appreciated for your help. Thanks for your time!

Comment: Does ` FillCamerasListView()` call `view.FillCamerasListView(connectedCameras)`? What is the assertion exception you are getting?

Comment: Ye, sure. SetUIOnNoConnectedDevices and FillCamerasListView which I call in presenter are just a simple wrappers on view.FillCamerasListView and view.SetUIOnNoConnectedDevices. I'm getting exception on this string view.Received().FillCamerasListView(argument); in test.

Comment: Exception error:
An exception of type 'NSubstitute.Exceptions.ReceivedCallsException' occurred in NSubstitute.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: Expected to receive a call matching:

 FillCamerasListView(List<String>)

Actually received no matching calls.

Received 1 non-matching call (non-matching arguments indicated with '*' characters):

 FillCamerasListView(*List<String>*)

Comment: It looks like wrapper is modifying the argument passed to FillCamerasListView. Can you post that wrapper?

Comment: Sure, but there aren't any modifications.
http://pastebin.com/N2UZ1gQp

Comment: `connectedCameras.GetCameraNames`? I think the problem is the view is called with a different argument. You can try `ReceivedWithAnyArgs` or `Arg.Is` with a condition that inspects the argument for the properties you need.

Comment: Somewhy it helps, thank you. But it's very strange for me, coz argument which I pass in view is just a property of argument, which I pass in presenter. It's mistery for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This example passes](https://gist.github.com/dtchepak/213a1b61ee8ea77299f7ee9690aad2ae). The problem appears to be something in your example that is changing the argument passed to `FillCamerasListView` as discussed in the comments.

A few options:

1. Modify the code to match the test's expectation. i.e. pass the argument given to `Run` on to `FillCamerasListView`.
2. Use `view.ReceivedWithAnyArgs().FillCamerasListView(null)` to assert a call was made without worry about the specifics of the argument passed.
3. Use `view.Received().FillCamerasListView(Arg.Is<List<string>>(x => Matches(x, argument))`, where `Matches` is your own code which determines whether the argument given is correct based on the `argument` passed to `Run`.